# SearchView en Action Bar: problemas en la búsqueda

Tags: android, searchview

¡Hola!
He hecho una aplicación a la que le he añadido la opción de búsqueda en la action bar. Tal cual está, funciona, pero no es exactamente lo que quiero. Cuando hago cualquier búsqueda, me remite a Google y yo lo que quiero es que busque en una dirección concreta con los términos que añada el usuario, exactamente en: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q= (añadiendo los términos que el usuario busque, es decir https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q + query).
Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
private static final String GOOGLEBOOKS_REQUEST_URL =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";


private static final int BOOK_LOADER_ID = 1;


private BookAdapter mAdapter;


private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

    ListView bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    bookListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

    mAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, new ArrayList<BookItem>());

    bookListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    bookListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            BookItem currentBookItem = mAdapter.getItem(position);

            Uri bookUri = Uri.parse(currentBookItem.getmPreviewURL());

            Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, bookUri);

            startActivity(websiteIntent);
        }
    });

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();


        loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    } else {

        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<List<BookItem>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new BookLoader(this, GOOGLEBOOKS_REQUEST_URL);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BookItem>> loader, List<BookItem> bookItems) {
    View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_books);

    mAdapter.clear();


    if (bookItems != null && !bookItems.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addAll(bookItems);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<BookItem>> loader) {
    mAdapter.clear();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem mShareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mShareItem);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    MenuItem mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchManager mSearchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(mSearchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search");
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share if you like!");
    return shareIntent;
}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Toast.makeText(this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent googleIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    googleIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    startActivity(googleIntent);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}

private Intent reachIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.google.es");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    return intent;
} }
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme para saber qué cambios tengo que hacer? Llevo un par de días con esto y no termino de aclararme.
Muchas gracias.
Saludos

Comment: Ya está resuelto, gracias